# Jquery in-line messages and validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Is it possible to add a custom message per element within a form, but do it inline?  For example:

```
<input type="text" name="mybox" id="mybox" class="required" requiredmessage="This is my custom message." />
```

I know you can use:

```
$('#myForm').validate();
```

to set custom messages, but wondering if I am able to do it inline like I can for the rules?

Comment: You can use custom data attributes in HTML5. For example data-requiredMessage="this is my custom message". For what rules?

Comment: Just saying in general and for all rules.  Don't want to have to write extra javascript for each form, if I can just set the custom message for each error on the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to set the custom message as the title attribute. So for example you could do the following:

```
<input type="text" class="required" title="This is my custom message." />
```

I hope that helps.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<input type="text" name="mybox" id="mybox" class="required" data-msg-required="This is my custom message." />
```